# How do I filter out this horizon from my contour?

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv

I am trying to identify the T-rex and obstacles (cactus and bird) from Google's no-internet game.

What I have done is:

- Apply GaussianBlur filter
- Apply Canny
- Apply Dilate
- Apply erode
- findContours that returns all external contours, RETR_EXTERNAL

My approach generally works, except that when there is a small bump on the ground next to a cactus, my script will consider the T-rex, the bump on the ground and the cactus as a giant horizontal contour, how do I filter out this horizon? The blue box is the outline of the contour I found.

- I tried reducing the size of the image I am taking vertically so that the horizon would be left out, but it introduced a different problem: T-rex legs would be cut off and occasionally, T-rex would not be considered as a contour as it is not closed.

[image]

When there is no bump on the ground next to a cactus, my script produces the expected result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a function provided by opencv2, threshold().

With this function, I can apply different combinations of threshold values so that this horizon can be filtered out.

The current values I am using is:

```
cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```